# Laravel maatwebsite package data export problem

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using maatwebsite package in my laravel 7 project to download data form database in xlsx format. (reference Link: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-import-export-excel-csv-file-tutorialexample.html )
But I am clicking on the export button a empty file is downloading without any data.

controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use DB;
  
class ExcelController extends Controller
{
    
    public function export() 
    {
        $user=DB::table('admin')->get();
        return Excel::download($user,'users.xlsx');
    }
 }
```

blade.php:

```
  <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export User Data</a>
```

route:

```
  Route::get('export', 'ExcelController@export')->name('export');
```

It is only downloading a empty file,how to get all data of admin table in xlsx format

Comment: I mean, you aren't even following that tutorial, why are you just passing the `$users` to `Excel::download()`? you need to create a export class, explained in the tutorial and in the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/) which has a 5 min quick start guide, making the tutorial completely unnecessary.

Comment: can't I download xlsx file without a model? I don''t have any admin model

Comment: You don't need a admin model, you can just use the [fromQuery concern](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html), and pass `DB::table('admin')` instead of `return Invoice::query();`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Export Class (pass model in `--model` parameter) considering you have already created `App\Admin` model.

```
php artisan make:export AdminsExport --model=Admin
```

2. Write in export class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Admin;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class AdminsExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Admin::all();
    }
}
```

3. Write this code in your controller file

```
return Excel::download(new AdminsExport, 'admins.xlsx');
```

Comment: can't I download xlsx file without a model? I don''t have any admin model

Comment: try `return collect(DB::table('admin')->all())`, this returns collection.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code for you to export data using `maatwebsite` package:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('export', 'ExcelController@export')->name('export');
```

**blade file**

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export User Data</a>
```

Create an export class in `app/Exports`

You may do this by using the `make:export` command.

```
php artisan make:export UsersExport --model=User
```

you can use the model name or table name from which you are trying to download the data

The file can be found in `app/Exports` as `Users Export`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        //add your own code here. below is just a sample code
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

**In your controller you can call this export now:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Reference is [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/)

Comment: can't I download xlsx file without a model? I don''t have any admin model

Comment: you can create one model using artisan command php artisan make:model Admin

Comment: the way which you are using to export is for older version of the excel package and the way which uses it now is through models and i think that's the best approach because it's latest